# WPF DataGrid on Custom Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, panel

I create a custom panel :

```
public class TowColumnWrapPanel : Panel
{
  //Here have Dependency Properties: RowSpacing, ColumnSpacing, ColumnsCount

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        List<int> shownChildIndexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualChildrenCount; i++)
        {
            if (Children[i].Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                shownChildIndexes.Add(i);
        }
        if (shownChildIndexes.Count == 1)
        {
           //on my example I use the code below:

            var child = Children[shownChildIndexes[0]];
            var r = new Rect(0, 0, arrangeSize.Width, arrangeSize.Height);
            if (child as FrameworkElement != null)
                (child as FrameworkElement).MaxWidth = arrangeSize.Width; 
            child.Arrange(r);
        }
        else
        {
           //Some functionality here for lot childs!! 
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }
}
```

Meaning of the above class is that all children will have the same size, and will be stretched on one column / two column (optional to the user)

**Everything works well!**

Except of course for the **DataGrid**!!!!

When I have a DataGrid on my custom panel. It looks like this:

Before resize (it's fine):
[image]

After Resize: (Somehow adds infinite column)

[image]

I don't understand why is happened, a little help would help!

Comment: The purpose of adding code is so that we can test it in a new project... it's *not* just there to make the question look pretty. However, your code does *not* demonstrate your problem because you have omitted relevant material.

Comment: Looks like last DataGrid column has fixed width set, Width='*' should make it take all remaining space. And yes, it's hard to see how's your code snippet relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this function: `MeasureOverride` - can be seen at the link below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238307/A-Two-Column-Grid-for-WPF

This is what **caused the problems** in the DG.